# Cannot instantiate pubnub sdk in angular 2 + typescript application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, pubnub

I am trying to use the pubnub javascript 4.0 sdk within my Angular 2 application that is using Typescript. I have successfully installed the library through npm and linked the module using SystemJS, and I can import it into my service that I'm using for chat. The problem comes when I try to access it within the service itself, I get a Error: CompileMetadataResolver. There are no type definitions for this library, so I found an open source .d.ts file someone posted online. Am I missing a type file (hence the metadata resolve)?

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {PUBNUB} from 'pubnub';

export class ChatService {
  private pnService: PUBNUB.PUBNUB;


  constructor(private pubNub: PUBNUB){
    //trying to access or create object here results in error
    this.pnService = new 
  }
  
  initialize(subkey:string, pubKey:string) {
   //this.pubNub.init({subscribe_key : subKey, publish_key : pubKey, ssl: true, origin: 'pubsub.pubnub.com'});
  }


}
```